# How to make Internet Explorer support Java applets?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, java-applet, browser-plugin

I have set `JAVA_HOME` and put `JAVA_HOME/bin` to `PATH` variable.

But Internet Explorer still doesn't support Java applets. Why?

Comment: Mine "just worked" after installing java (but you may need to install 32-bit java FWIW).

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I enable Java in my web browser?](http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

**Internet Explorer**

1. Click `Tools (Alt+X) / Internet Options`
2. Select `Security tab / Custom Level button`
3. Scroll down to `Scripting of Java applets` and make sure the `Enable` radio button is checked
4. Click `OK` to save your preference

**Chrome**

1. Click on `Wrench` icon / Options`
2. Select `Under the Hood / Privacy Content Settings` (the Content Settings panel will appear)
3. In the `Plug-ins` section, select the `Disable individual plug-ins` link to check whether Java is enabled
4. Click on the `Enable` link (if the `Disable` link appears, Java is already enabled)

Comment: that was no such option ... in fact i don't install jdk, but extract one jdk from zip file

Comment: For IE to display applets, you need the Java plugin installed which comes with the JRE. If you have some sort of portable install, it's probably not gonna work in IE (you can use the [appletviewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/appletviewer.html) though). Also, you should have mentioned your non-standard setup details in the question.